# How to send an AJAX post with concatenated data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to do an ajax POST passing in the data multiple parameters, is the following format correct?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://www.citroen.it/_/Layout_Citroen_PointsDeVente/getStoreList',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
    'lat': +45.66 + 'long': +12.23 + 'page': +6149 + 'version': 43 + 'order': 2 + 'area': 150 + 'ztid': '' + 'attribut': '' + 'brandactivity': ''
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('errore');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can not do a POST with JSONP. JSONP is a GET request. Your `data` line is wrong, you do not use a "+" inside of an object for each parameter.

Comment: ok, you right, but with json only i have a XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Comment: You cannot concatenate in an object. You need to set the key/value pairs separately. Also note that this AJAX request will not work. If you check the response from the request you'll see that it's JSON, not JSONP. If you change the `dataType` to `json` you'll get a different error stating: `No Access Control headers` because the third party URL you're calling does not include CORS in the response. The outcome of all of this means that what you're trying to do will not work (as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uud1rbyv/).  You need to make the request server side instead

Comment: You also can not just make a JSONP call unless the service supports JSONP.

Comment: ok, thanks, any idea how to not have XMLHttpRequest error?

Comment: Unless you have control of the `citroen.it` domain, then you can't get around the problem.